# Second Level Subdomains in Azure Apps

Tags: azure, subdomain

I've looked everywhere and can't find what I exactly want. A second-level subdomain in azure itself and not in a custom domain name. I've done that with my other domain using cname and a records.

I need to do something like ABC.XYZ.cloudapp.net
Every article I read presumes I have a custom domain, I still didn't buy one for this roject.
My current project is for a wordpress multisite so want to do something like 
portfolio.myapp.cloudapp.net
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment. However, there is a feedback request for it: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/6119382-subdomain-cloudapp-net-etc-rather-than-having-a

Comment: too bad the idea is still in development since 2014. But thanks for the information and the link. Wanted to upvote your answer but I have less than 15 reps.

Comment: @nassim just flag the answer as the right one, you will also start earning points.

Comment: its now 2019 and im still waiting for this