# How can I create a sub sub domain to the Azure cloudapp.net domain?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I have a sub domain assigned from Azure:

**sub.cloudapp.net**

I want a sub sub domain:

**sub.sub.cloudapp.net**

I have tried to create a DNS zone in Azure portal and added a CNAME:

**sub.sub.cloudapp.net -> sub.cloudapp.net**

When I check "$ host" using the azure dns server I get:

> Using domain server: Name: ns1-05.azure-dns.com Address: xx.xx.x.x#53
>   Aliases:
>
> sub.sub.cloudapp.net is an alias for
>   sub.cloudapp.net.

When I check regular "$ host" without using the dns server I get (after 1 hour DNS propagation time):

> Host sub.sub.cloudapp.net not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

I this the correct way to do it? Or should I wait more for the propagation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like second-level subdomain is not supported, check out here: [Second Level Subdomains in Azure Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250168/second-level-subdomains-in-azure-apps)

Comment: The UserVoice request was made in 2014, feels like this is an unlikely feature.